# Path in Express 4.x routing

Tags: express, routes

I would like to understand the full capabilities of Express's path parameter in routing. Currently, all that I can gather from the API documentation is that

```
// this will only be invoked if the path ends in /bar
router.use('/bar', function(req, res, next)
```

But does it respond to regex? Can I put optional parameters? Basically what can I exactly do and can't do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It does support regular expression.

Please check the [api-doc](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html)

From the api doc's here is an example

```
app.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){
    var from = req.params[0];
    var to = req.params[1] || 'HEAD';
    res.send('commit range ' + from + '..' + to);
});
```

I am not sure what you meant by optional parameter? You can achieve it by regular expression if you want to match multiple things to same route.